# i have a file and i need to extract a particular string followed after the regex 'LN:' from the second line

Tags: regex, awk

please refer the file contents below.

```
    @HD VN:1.0  SO:unsorted
    @SQ SN:Chr1 LN:30427680
    @PG ID:bowtie2  PN:bowtie2  VN:2.1.0
```

how can i extract just the number 30427680 using awk or any other unix command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using grep:

```
grep -oP 'LN:\K.*' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Using sed

```
sed -n 's/.*LN://p' < input.txt
```

This will erase everything up until `LN:`, and print what's left, and only if a substitution did take place.

#### Using awk

```
awk -v FS=: '/LN:/ { print $3; }' < input.txt
```

This will match lines that contain `LN:`, use `:` as field separator, and print the 3rd column.

#### Using grep

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{3,\}' < input.txt
```

This will match sequences of 3 or more digits, and print only the matched pattern thanks to the `-o`.

Depending on other cases not included in your question, you might have to make the patterns more strict.

Answer (score 0):

Just use grep:

```
grep -o 30427680 file

-o, --only-matching
         Prints only the matching part of the lines.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -ne 'print $& if /LN:\K.*/' filename
```

or

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if /LN:(.*)/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`

```
awk -F"LN:" 'NF>1 {print $2}' file
```